# Access Denied error when accessing catalog_product from custom module and logged in from other than admin

Tags: magento, permissions

I have created a custom module, in the module when I click Save button sends request to catalog_products save function and save data to my extension's tables only(I have changed core file for this). Url on which I send request is:

localhost/magento/index.php/admin/admin/catalog_product/save/id/71/key5QDhzOH0ZRIgYZIC/?form_key=5QDhzOH0ZRIgYZIC&from_bpstore=yes

I have used ajax to save my data. And it is saving data when logged in from user having role "Administrator" but as I log in from any other user then it gives "Access Denied" error in response. Following is my config.xml for custom module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
   <modules>
     <Bp_BpstoreInfo>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
     </Bp_BpstoreInfo>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <bpstoreinfo>
        <class>Bp_BpstoreInfo_Helper</class>
      </bpstoreinfo>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <bpstoreinfo>
        <class>Bp_BpstoreInfo_Block</class>
      </bpstoreinfo>
   </blocks>
 </global>
<admin>
  <routers>
    <bpstoreinfo>
      <use>admin</use>
       <args>
        <module>Bp_BpstoreInfo</module>
        <frontName>bpstoreinfo</frontName>
       </args>
    </bpstoreinfo>
 </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
 <menu>
      <bpstoreinfo module="bpstoreinfo">
        <title>Room Prices</title>
        <sort_order>77</sort_order>
        <action>bpstoreinfo/adminhtml_bpstoreinfobackend</action>
      </bpstoreinfo>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <bpstoreinfo>
                        <title>bpstoreinfo Module</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    </bpstoreinfo>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
</acl>
<layout>
  <updates>
    <bpstoreinfo>
      <file>bpstoreinfo.xml</file>
    </bpstoreinfo>
  </updates>
</layout>
 </adminhtml>
 </config>
```

And my controller of custom module is

```
<?php
  class Bp_BpstoreInfo_Adminhtml_BpstoreinfobackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
 {
     public function indexAction()
     {
        $this->loadLayout();    
        $this->_title($this->__("Booking Prices"));
        $this->renderLayout();
     }

 }
```

But when Ajax runs it sends data to catalog product module, Is this the problem that I am not able to save my data.
Please help I am totally stuck here. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does your controller implement `_isAllowed()` ?

Comment: yes it has _isAllowed() function.